# barbushin imap-php textPlain contains base64 images when .eml file is attached

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments, email

I've implemented barbushin imap-php with out any issues.

Issue:
`textPlain` value contains base64 encoded attachment(s).
It seems if an email is received with .eml (backup email) file attached, and the .eml file contains an image this image is then part of the emails text.

Question:
Is there a way to ignore or extract the .eml file from the mails origin text received?

Answer (score 0):

What I found is using the [imap_fetchbody](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php)
with `$section = empty( $attachments ) ? 1 : 1.1;`
This helped me to archive the desired output.